# Comparing the Widths of two Posterior Distributions

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, posterior, jags, bugs

I have a question regarding the task of my term paper case study, which is about Bayesian multilevel modelling and I would greatly appreciate it, if you could help me out.

The exact assignment reads as follows:

> Estimate Bayesian random-intercept-random-slope hierarchical models
>   using an R package and a sampling engine of your choice (BUGS, JAGS or
>   Stan) based on simulated or empirical multilevel data
>
> - Do sensitivity analysis using different priors
> - Re-estimate your model ignoring the multilevel structure, and compare the    widths of the posterior predictive distributions of y based on the simple and the hierarchical model

So I did just what it says, I fitted one multilevel model with the lmer function from the lme4 package (on a suitable real life dataset) and one with Jags, giving very similiar results. I then fitted a third model complete pooling model with Jags, which ignores the multilevel structure.

However, I do not quite understand what is meant by "compare the widths of the posterior distribution". For me it would make sense to conduct a performance analysis of the two models that were fitted with Jags. So ideally one would show that explicitly modelling the multilevel structure of the data, would significantly improve the explanatory or predictive power of our model.

However, I do not understand how measuring the width (=range) of the resulting posterior distribution would be a meaningful way of measuring the quality of our model. Do you have an idea what the intention behind comparing the widths of the posterior distributions would be?

Of course, the best person to ask would be my supervisor, but he is unfortunately unavailabe for some time and there is no way to ask him before the submission deadline.

In advance, Thank you very much for your thoughts!

Comment: If you have a posterior distribution, it will have some measure of scale you can calculate (e.g. range, standard deviation, IQR, credible interval width) and the wider this is, the greater your uncertainty in predicting $y$.  Presumably the simple and the hierarchical models will give you noticeably different widths

Comment: The width is very important, as  to narrow gives false sense of precision. To wide and the probabilty mass is spans to many values that should not be included in the higher density interval, for example. The width is thus critical for inference.

Comment: Henry, D_Williams Thank you very much for your quick replies. 


So I used the 2.5%, 25%, 50%, 75% and 95% quantiles for the different parameters and I was surprised to see that the width of the multilevel model is significantly greater but has smaller residuals.


So is it legitimate to say that the complete pooling model greatly underestimates the real variance?